# Telerik Error - Parameter name: panelsCreated[6]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a simple page that uses telerik:RadAjaxManager.

For some reason on page load I'm getting this error in browser console:

[image]

I googled it, and found lots of articles where they say I need to switch off debug mode in web.config. So it would hide the error, but it doesn't solve it at all.

Any suggestions?